# Arithmetic progression of primes question

Tags: prime-numbers

Is it known whether for all positive integers $k$ there is an integer $a$ such that $a+30n$ is a prime number for all $n\in \{1,\ldots,k\}$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: There is no such a progression because of modulo 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$k$ cannot be larger than $6$, since among any seven numbers of the form $b, b + 30, b + 60, \ldots, b + 180$ at least one of them is divisible by $7$, and hence only a prime if it *is* seven. But if $b = 7$, then $187 = 11\cdot 17$ is not a prime.

That being said, $b = 7, k = 6$ is one maximal example (w.r.t. $k$)as
$$
7, 37, 67, 97, 127, 157
$$
are all prime. There may be more examples.

Also note that it was proven in 2004 that for any $k$, there is a prime $p$ and a difference $d$ such that the numbers
$$
p, \,p + d,\, p + 2d, \ldots, p + (k-1)d 
$$
are all prime (the [Green-Tao theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem)).

Comment: I read the question more carefully than you :-)

Comment: @TonyK I am aware that the asker starts counting at $1$ and I start at $0$, but I do not see the big difference as long as the _number of terms_ are correct (technically $a = -23, k = 6$ is the example I've shown, yes, I know). Let's say I use $b$ instead, just to make you happy.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers $a+30,a+60,\ldots,a+210$ are all distinct mod $7$, so one of them must be divisible by 7. So your conjecture fails.